# Android SSLKEYLOGFILE

Tags: android, google-chrome, security, firefox

it's the first time I post here. I have a project at my university about android. I would like to be able to store SSLKeys in a file in my android like in Windows SSLKEYLOGFILE. As you can find that [tutorial](https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/Psst+Your+Browser+Knows+All+Your+Secrets/16415/) which I was able to do it successfully the keys are stored in a file and using wireshark I can decrypt the traffic. Is there something similar to android. I have a rooted android device. 
Thanks.